# Low fps on The Witcher 2 even though it should be better

Tags: the-witcher-2, graphics-card, framerate

so I have a graphics card in my Lenovo e560 laptop with the following specifications:

Graphics Card Manufacturer - Powered by AMD

Graphics Chipset - AMD Radeon (TM) R7 M370
Memory Size - 2048 MB
Memory Type - GDDR5
Memory Clock - 900 MHz
Core Clock - 875 MHz
Total Memory Bandwidth - 57 GByte/s

And [this website](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Computer-Games-on-Laptop-Graphics-Cards.13849.0.html) tells me that my video card is better than the [minimum requirement](http://www.futuremark.com/hardware/gpu/AMD+Radeon+HD+6570/review) and that I should run The Witcher at medium settings at around 40fps but this is not the case. I get 25fps at best with all the settings extremely low. I even downloaded a mod that reduces the graphics even further... what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your drivers at http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Also websites like that aren't the best at determinating how the game will actually run on your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the game exe file to Switchable Graphics.

1. Open AMD Radeon Settings.
2. Go to "System".
3. Go to "Switchable Graphics".
4. Click "Running Applications" button and change it to "Installed Profile Applications".
5. Click "Browse" button and add the game's exe file to it.
6. Set it to High Performance.

For better performance plug in your laptop and don't play when your laptop is on battery.